# Add incremental number before item name on WooCommerce order emails

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, email-notifications

I have a WooCommerce store and everything is working well. But I would like to **add a number in front of every item name** when an order is placed so I can put numbers on the box so the customer knows which box contains what product.

(I only have 1 product but the custommer can customize that product with a lot of product options)

**Example:** in the order email, the product name stays the same but an incremental number is placed in front of the name.

1. product
2. product
3. product

I use this code to edit the product name:

```php
add_filter( 'woocommerce_order_item_name', 'change_orders_items_names', 10, 1 );

function change_orders_items_names( $item_name ) {
    $item_name = 'mydesiredproductname';
    return $item_name;
}
```

---

But I do not know how to add an incremental number to the product name.

Is there anyone who knows how to do this? Or can point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `woocommerce_order_item_name` filter hook is called multiple times,
therefore it is difficult to add a number in the function itself.

Via `woocommerce_checkout_create_order` we first add the number as `meta_data` for each `$item`. Afterwards via `get_meta`, we add the number in front of the product name.

So you get:

```php
function action_woocommerce_checkout_create_order( $order, $data ) {    
    // Start number
    $number = 1;
    
    // Loop through order items
    foreach ( $order->get_items() as $item_key => $item ) {
        // Update meta data for each item
        $item->update_meta_data( '_product_number', $number );
    
        // Number +1
        $number = $number + 1;
    }
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_create_order', 'action_woocommerce_checkout_create_order', 10, 2 );

function filter_woocommerce_order_item_name( $item_name, $item ) {  
    // Get meta
    $product_number = $item->get_meta( '_product_number' );
    
    // NOT empty
    if ( ! empty ( $product_number ) ) {
        $item_name = $product_number . '. ' . $item_name; 
    }

    return $item_name;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_order_item_name', 'filter_woocommerce_order_item_name', 10, 2 );
```

---

**Note:** add `is_wc_endpoint_url`, to apply it only for email notifications.

```php
function filter_woocommerce_order_item_name( $item_name, $item ) {
    // Only for email notifications
    if ( is_wc_endpoint_url() ) 
        return $item_name;

    // Get meta
    $product_number = $item->get_meta( '_product_number' );
    
    // NOT empty
    if ( ! empty ( $product_number ) ) {
        $item_name = $product_number . '. ' . $item_name; 
    }

    return $item_name;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_order_item_name', 'filter_woocommerce_order_item_name', 10, 2 );
```